# How can I make two numbers transition smoothly between two heights?

Tags: functions

I am attempting to set something to be a different colour depending on the height it is.

For example, if the height is between 0 and 80, I would like `black` to equal 1. If it is between 80 and 120, I would `red` to equal 1, if it's between 120 and 200 I would like to be `green`, and if it's between 200 and 255 I would like to be `blue`.

All four variables need to add up to "1" every time, or else everything will go wrong.

In itself, it would be easy:

```
if (height < 80) black = 1;
etc....
```

However, the problem is, I would like there to be a smooth transition.

For example, if the height equals 70, I would like `black` to be 0.7, and `red` to be 0.3, and all the other numbers remain as 0. If it was 80, I would like both numbers to equal 0.5, and if it was 90, I would like `red` to be 0.7 and `black` to be 0.3.

How could I do this with the least possible calculations? I will be implementing this on the graphics card, so a method with the least possible calculations would be very much appreciated (since I will have to run this code every time a pixel is drawn on the screen).

Answer (score 5):

Degree 3 "spline" polynomials. Basically, $3t^2-2t^3$, with $t$ retargeted to the numbers of your case. Especially when programming on a graphics card, in glsl you have *smoothstep* doing exactly that: see derivations, figures and API in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep

Comment: I'm slightly confused here, probably because my mathematical notation isn't really the best. Could you perhaps explain what I actually need to do to get the result?

Comment: something like red = smoothstep(50,80,h)*smoothstep(150,120,h), and same for green and blue. just try here: https://www.shadertoy.com/new

Comment: Now, it also depends the kind of color interpolation you want in transitions: RGB or HLS ?  (i.e. like fading R,G,B light spots, ordre like traveling in rainbow colors)

Comment: That "ShaderToy" site doesn't seem to recognize smoothstep() as a method. The point is, I still don't know what these methods do nor how I would use them, nor what mathematical solution I would want/need. Could you perhaps update your answer to be more informative about that?

Comment: Man, I gave you the wikipedia link with math formula, pseudo code, figure, and explanations. Plus an example. Have you read them ?

Comment: And smoothstep is just used, like, in probably half of the examples in shadertoy, + in its documentation ('?' icon below code area).

Comment: The mathematical calculation you stated makes no sense, because I would need more variables than just "t" to get any result at all. Also, you haven't explained how to use SmoothStep or how I can use it to make all four numbers equal 1 - You've simply linked me to a Wikipedia article which is useless in terms of actually implementing it in my code. There are no real examples nor pseudo code, nor do I actually comprehend the mathematical formulas that it is trying to present. In ShaderToy, I copied in your smoothstep code and it didn't work. It complained about stuff I didn't even change.

Comment: if you want the sum to be 1,  just swap the bounds, ore use $weight_g = 1-weight_r$. I implemented it for you: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llSSWV
Note that the color at transition are not pretty, but are such r+g = 1. Sometime people prefer to convert r,g,b to hue,luminance,saturation, and interpolate de hue (i.e., the chrominance). In the shadertoy exemple, x is in [0,1]. for [0,255], you would scale the bounds in smoothstep. The exemple is for one transition. just multiply the various transitions.

Comment: Ugh, I still don't get it. I'll just leave the issue for now and try and implement it when it's a bit more urgent.

Comment: I just implemented the complete answer on the bottom half of https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llSSWV